# ReactJs component data from web api

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to get data to my react js component from web api.

```
    var FormList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState:function(){
        return {data:[]}
    }
    render: function(){
        var FormNodes = this.props.data.map(function(form) {
            <div>
            {form.UserWho}
            </div>
            });
        return (
            {FormNodes}
            );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <FormList url="/replacements/" />,
    document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

I am getting 500 Internal server error

> GET http://localhost:61256/Scripts/Replacement.jsx 500 (Internal Server Error)

When I am trying to get json data directly from localhost/replacements it works and returns it. I set the breakpoint for replacements method but debugger doesnt reach it (it reaches it only when I manually go to localhost/replacements). Any ideas whats wrong?

@EDIT
I also tried using ajax but the same problem - get method isn't even reached.

Comment: In some frameworks like ASP.NET, the JSX mime-type is not set to be processed by the appropriate handler. We do some additional settings on IIS to allow JSX to be directly available. Also, in the build process, JSX undergoes transpilation / compilation to JavaScript.

Comment: Thats may be a solution. Could you tell me, how should I configure IIS?

Comment: I thought about that, but normally jsx file works on my server (without getting data from url it displaying components correctly). The problem is the FormList doesnt get data from url (debbuger breakpoint doesnt stop).